# No events registered with SemanticLogging service on single server

Tags: c#, enterprise-library, etw, semantic-logging, slab

I'm trying to get SemanticLogging-svc.exe from the Enterprise Library Semantic Logging Application Block to listen to events for my custom event source and dump them to console.

This works fine for my localhost and for a development server, but I don't get any output for a production server. So I'm looking for answers as to why that might be.

The console output is simply:

```
Event Trace Session prefix: Microsoft-SemanticLogging-Etw

Sink name: ConsoleEventSink
Event sources:
Name: b3b81ce4-1cb6-512c-f02f-46aefff0344d
INNOMATE-HR-Security, Level: LogAlways, MatchAnyKeyword: None

Service started.
```

My SemanticLogging-svc.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2013/entlib/semanticlogging/etw"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2013/entlib/semanticlogging/etw SemanticLogging-svc.xsd">
  <traceEventService/>
  <sinks>
    <consoleSink name="ConsoleEventSink">
      <sources>
        <eventSource name="INNOMATE-HR-Security" level="LogAlways"/>
      </sources>
      <eventTextFormatter header="+=========================================+"/>
    </consoleSink>
  </sinks>
</configuration>
```

There are no events in the Windows Event Log.

I've also tried with a rollingFlatFileSink. This results in an empty file on the production server, but works on the other systems.

Looking in PerfMon > Data Collector Sets > Event Trace Sessions, I see that Microsoft-SemanticLogging-Etw-ConsoleEventSink is running.

Using PerfView, my events are collected correctly.

The server in question is an older one, running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Is there some setting I'm missing, or does anyone have another explanation of why this isn't working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the identity of the SemanticLogging-svc service does not have the required permissions to create an ETW session, register a provider or read events from an ETW session.

Add the identity of the SemanticLogging-svc service instance to the `Performance Log Users` Windows group.

Have you tried running the SemanticLogging-svc service with the same account you had used for `PerfView` or with administrator privileges?

Comment: The problem is there both when running SemanticLogging-svc as a console app (with the -console argument) and as a service - both with full administrator privieges. Adding the Performance Log Users group explicitly does not help, either.

Comment: What's the OS and .Net version in your other environments?

Comment: And in production as well.

Comment: Dev: Windows 10 Enterprise, .NET 4.6.1 (works).
Test: Windows Server 2012 R2, Standard, .NET 4.6.1 (works).
Prod: Windows Server 2008 R2, .NET 4.5.2 (doesn't work).
I'll try upgrading to .NET 4.6.1 on the production server and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Upgrading to .NET 4.6.1 on production did not change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Now I just guess: try deleting the manifest file under C:\Users\{eventConsumerIdentity}\AppData\Local\Temp\7D2611AE-6432-4639-8B91-3E46‌​EB56CADF

Comment: I found the folder (it was actually at "....\AppData\Local\Temp\2\7D2611AE-6432-4639-8B91-3E46EB56CADF" - note the "\2\") and deleted it. No effect. It gets recreated when starting SemanticLogging-svc and the manifest is created (so the events are occurring) and is identical to the one from the other systems. So, no luck so far, but thanks a lot for your effort :-) If you have any other suggestions, they would be very welcome.